# World of Warcraft API: Return value from PutItemInBag()

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any return value from PutItemInBag(), possibly telling you if it succeeded or the bag was full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a return value, but that only returns whether the cursor had an item. See [FrameXML/MainMenuBarBagButtons.lua#L20](https://github.com/Gethe/wow-ui-source/blob/2ca215b373e6107bdc7f1e2715fc0c2ec4720a14/FrameXML/MainMenuBarBagButtons.lua#L20)

```lua
hadItem = PutItemInBag(inventoryID)
```

The [UI_ERROR_MESSAGE](https://wow.gamepedia.com/UI_ERROR_MESSAGE) event will [fire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Bfl.png) with errorType 13 if a bag is full